# Identifying ID of adjacent pipelines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, adjacency

I work with ArcGIS. In the picture you can see several pipelines, more over pipeID's A; 1; 2; 3
I would like to have as an output the following columns and rows:

- A - 1;
- A - 2;
- A - 3;

As an inputfile I have a polyline file. I have taken a buffer around it of 0.5 meters and then I tried to spatially join this buffer file with the original shapeline file, using "Within". Nevertheless this does not deliver me the requested matches as I hoped. 
Does anyone have an idea on how I should do this?

[image: Pipelines with explanation]
[image: Pipelines with buffer of 0.5 meter around]

Comment: Sorry its not entirely clear what we are looking at, is pipeline "A" a small  segment?

Answer (score 1):

Because I cannot see where 'A' lies (is it just a segment where all the pipes join, or does it actually follow the length of 1, 2 and 3), I am taking a stab at what I think *might* be the problem.

'Are Within' (from ArcGIS Help link within Selection Dialog Box, or, [ESRI Select By Location Web Help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm)):

> To be selected, the geometry of the target feature must fall inside the geometry of the source feature. Selected features and source features can have overlapping boundaries.
>   So, if, segment 1, 2, and/or 3 actually fall outside of the boundary of 'A', they will not be selected by the selection statement.

If you believe that these segments should be completely encompassed by 'A', I suggest looking very closely at the edges. You may need to apply a buffer and use 'Are Within a Distance of' instead.

If 'A' is only where the other pipes all intersect, than you'll need to use an 'Intersect' as the criteria of the join.

Once you are able to get the data to intersect as expected, adding a new column and using 'Field Calculator' to combine the values of table 1 to table 2 should be simple enough.